# How do I get edit, copy, delete to show in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I can't figure out how to get Edit, Copy, Delete to show in phpmyadmin.

[image]

Here is what I want:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have sufficient privileges in the database to do the things you want?

Comment: When I created that test table above (through phpmyadmin) the options showed up. It's only on the tables that start with sf_ that the options don't show up. How can I change this? I only have one database user at the moment.

Comment: Nevermind got it working by setting a unique/primary key

Answer (score 30):

Make sure you have made one of the columns a primary key. This can be done in 'Structure' and if you select a column then click primary this should make give it a unique id.

Comment: Structure -> Relation view -> +Index

Answer (score 11):

Just add auto-increment options to any of field

Comment: Yes, when I exported my DB I did not have the auto increment options checked within PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the following in your `config.inc.php` file of `phpmyadmin`

```
 $cfg['RowActionLinksWithoutUnique'] = 'true';
```

and restart the `mysql` engine